# How to decide between Helpers and Services namespaces?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there any general guideline to place a class under the Helpers namespace or the Services namespace? I have seen many sample codes and cannot find a pattern. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to think of Helpers as those things which are referenced in your View to display some HTML, while Services would be those things which are referenced in a Controller (or another Service) to manipulate data, etc.

I don't know if there is a recognised standard, but if I were to pick up your code, that would be my initial guess.

Answer (score -1):

**Do what makes sense to you and your team.**

Comment: Thank you jfar, but before getting there, I need to make sure if there is any standard in the development community.

Comment: @Bruno Ligutti: I understand your question.